# How to notify parent about failing child component rules in vuejs / vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a "child" component that comes with its own rules. As an simplyfied example an input field that may contain only the values "A" or "B"

```
    <template>
        <v-text-field 
            v-model="loaded" 
            :rules="[v => v === 'A' || v === 'B' || 'must be A | B']">
            </my-input>
    </template>

    <script lang="ts">
    import Vue from "vue"

    export default Vue.extend({
        name: "MyInput",
        props: {
            item: {
                type: String,
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                loaded: this.item,
            }
        },
        watch: {
            loaded: {
                handler(nv: boolean) {
                    this.$emit("update", nv)
                }
            }
        },
    });
    </script>
```

Now this component and its rules work as expected on their own.

However I want to embedd this component into a "parent" that is a "form" like this

```
<template>
    <v-form v-model="isValid">
        <my-input v-model="value"></my-input>
    </v-form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue"

import MyInput from './MyInput.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    components: { MyInput },
    name: "SomeView",
    data() {
        return {
            isValid: true,
            value: "A"
        }
    },
});
</script>
```

NowI want my "form" now to be notified about the (possible) effect of a failed rule within my child component.

How do I do this best?

I am using vuetify

Comment: Try moving your child rules logic into a separate method, and then emit an event to the parent from the same method if the rules are violated.

Comment: If you call the [validate](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#functions-validate) method on the form it should automatically validate your inputs even if they are in separate components.

Answer (score 0):

Usually communication between Vue parent and child components is done via props and events. Props go in, events come out.

```
<!-- this is in parent component template -->
<child-component
    :prop1="value1"
    @someevent="handleEvent()"
/>
```

```
// this is in child component script
onSomeEvent() {
    this.$emit('someevent', 'eventData');
}
```

See this for further reading: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

Comment: Well, yeah. Its certainly true that the ordinary way to comm between child and parent is event emitting however the case of a component with its own rules to be communicating with its parent specifically about failed rules seems to be like a special case and one would some expect that this special case is somehow implemented differenty (aka with less boilerplate)

Comment: I don't think there is a special way for that. I'd think the rules follow some common pattern, which the form can interpret. Which data you emit with the event is up to you and can be as special as you like. The parent form somehow has to react to that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, without using watchers would be to listen for the vuetify form [input change event](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#api-events). This function would be called only on change of the validity of the whole form. So, if your form is valid and somebody changes the value and it is still valid, nothing happens. But if somebody changes from valid to invalid or vice-versa, the handling function will be called.

Here is how it would look, on the example you gave above:

```
<template>
    <v-form @input="handleInputChange" v-model="isValid">
        <my-input v-model="value"></my-input>
    </v-form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue"

import MyInput from './MyInput.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    components: { MyInput },
    name: "SomeView",
    data() {
        return {
            isValid: true,
            value: "A"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleInputChange(validityOfForm) {
            console.log(validityOfForm);
        },
    }
});
</script>
```

Please note that this approach will not tell the parent which input field failed.